# SQL Merge tables with two different columns

Tags: sql, merge

I have two tables that look like this:

table1:

[image]

table2:

[image]

and I'd like to merge them, to create a table with a header like this:

```
variablenname | mean | stddev | ms_form | dependent | fvalue | probf
```

The first nine rows should be the first table with empty values in the last 3 columns followed by the three rows from the second table with empty values in the first 4 columns. I'm sorry I can't post pictures or a third link, but my reputation is too low. I hope it's understandable.

I tried to create a new table and select everything from both with `union` but that didn't work. Can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to put the table structure and sample data as text inside the questions, not in external images, so people can view it easily and copy/paste if they want to make tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ALTER to add the last 3 columns to table 1. From there, INSERT table 2 onto table 1. So something like this.

```
ALTER table1 ADD dependent varchar(16)
ALTER table1 ADD favalue varchar(16)
ALTER table1 ADD probf varchar(16)

INSERT INTO table1(dependent, fvalue, probf)
  SELECT * FROM table2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would like the final table to look like: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of joins and unions

`LEFT JOIN` the two tables in first query on fields that won't have a match
then `UNION` the second query with a `RIGHT JOIN` of the same tables.

The `LEFT JOIN` will only show results from the first table, then the `RIGHT JOIN` will only show results from the second

Something Like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 as t1 
LEFT JOIN table1 as t2 on t1.variablenname = t2.fValue 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM table1 as t1 
RIGHT JOIN table1 as t2 on t1.variablenname = t2.fValue;
```